# Ruby on Rails check-boxes and jointables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am new with ruby on rails so I have some troubles.

I made two models, Property and Feature, then I made a Jointable to communicate both of them.

NOTE: I made both of my models and my jointable with scaffold!!!

I add this in my properties controller

```html
def property_params
    params.require(:property).permit(:title, :description, feature_ids: [])
end
```

Just when I insert my data the checkboxes of the features appears, just like this:

```html
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Features" %><br />
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :feature_ids, Feature.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
    <div class="collection-check-box">
        <%= b.check_box %>
        <%= b.label %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

But when I try to show the new property I have no idea how to call the features that I select before, I just have the ids and I can show the ids but that's now what I want, if someone can help me I would appreciate it :)

Sorry for my bad English and thanks!

Comment: What is the relationship between Property and Feature? Maybe you could show us both models. You may be overcomplicating by adding a join table and what appear to be nested attributes. Also, is your collection_select part of a form? If yes, show the entire form. Show us that and we'll have a better shot at being of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading [activerecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). But for starters, i'll try to explain and clarify some of the things you are trying to do.

The only time when you need a joint-table between 2 models is when you are going for the `Many to Many` associations.

```
For example:
A property has many features.
A feature can be found in many properties.
```

So depending on your needs, you may not even need a joint-table.

Next would be calling on methods. You can essentially access any of the methods that are available to each class. Lets assume that in your `Property` table, you have a `name` column.

So naturally you are able to do something like this

```
Property.first.name
#returns the name of the first property in your database
```

**IF** you have a many to many association, then you are able to do something like this

```
foo = Feature.first
foo.properties 
#shows all Property that are associated with the first feature
foo.properties.first.name
#shows the name of the first property associated with the first feature
```

**BUT** for example if your association is *One-Directional*, meaning,

Property has many Features. Features belongs to Property.

You can access your `Features` through a `Property`, but you would not be able to find all the properties associated with a single `Feature`.